# Application.OnTime can't change time

Tags: excel, vba

I try to run the following code on specific time, the code ran very first time, after that when I change time it's not working, code is saved in `ThisWorkbook`.

Any Suggestions?

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
    'Run AlchemyTest_2 at 1:50 pm
    Application.OnTime ("1:50:00"), "AlchemyTest_2"
End Sub
```

Comment: `after that when I change time` - where and how do you change time?

Comment: ("1:50:00") between parenthesis

Comment: @user3877643 parenthesis in a parameter list just makes a read-only copy of an expression value.  This has no effect here since the parameter is read-only anyway.

Comment: Do you actually run this code again after you change the parameter, @user3877643?

Comment: GSerg thanks for your help, I just change time, wait for pc clock to turn at 1:50pm

Answer (score 1):

Since your code is contained in the `workbook_open` function, it will only run when you first open the workbook.

If you want to run that line of code, you can paste it into the immediate window (`Ctrl+G` if it isn't visible) and hitting enter.

The immediate window serves 2 purposes.  First, it provides a place for code to be entered that you want to be run immediately, and the output of that code, if it returns anything.  Second, it is the output location for `Debug.Print`.

You mention changing the time, which suggests that you are trying to to get `AlchemyTest_2` to run (almost) immediately.  If that is the case, you can either paste `AlchemyTest_2` into the immediate window and hit enter, or place your cursor in the function and run it (F5).

Comment: Degustaf thanks for you also helping me out, will explain the immediate window?

Answer (score -2):

The time supplied is *not* a delta time, it's absolute.  Try it like this instead:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
    'Run AlchemyTest_2 at 1:50 pm
    Application.OnTime Cdate(Clng(Now)) + TimeValue("13:50:00"), "AlchemyTest_2"
End Sub
```

Comment: If OP does this, and opens the workbook at 8AM, the code will run at 9:50, not 1:50, as is commented.

Comment: still same thing, nothing happening, not getting error either.

Comment: @user3877643 I fixed a mistake, try it again.

Comment: still nothing using the following code Private Sub workbook_open()
    'Run AlchemyTest_2 at 2:30 pm
    Application.OnTime CDate(CLng(Now)) + TimeValue("14:30:00"), "AlchemyTest_2"
End Sub